# how to print part of regex match in sed when parsing source code?

Tags: regex, parsing, sed, match

I would like to print part between regex match like this:

```
echo "this is foo and another foo quux" | sed 's/this\(.*\)another.*/\1/'
```

which prints

```
 is foo and
```

what is perfectly ok as I want to get part between this and another printed.

But, If I want to parse my source code and use:

```
cat source_code | sed 's/.*AdulterateFood\(.*\)DangerousFood.*/\1/'
```

and I do know that AdulterateFood and DangerousFood is only once in the source code, it still prints everything, whole file:( I am wondering why.. AdulterateFood and DangerousFood are on different lines.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sed prints each input line by default. If you don't want that behavior you need to add the -n option. If you then want it to print the lines that match your RE you have to add a "p" to the end of the substitution command to tell sed TO print that line. So this:

```
sed -n 's/.*AdulterateFood\(.*\)DangerousFood.*/\1/p' source_code
```

seems to be what you're asking for but since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output it's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

To print all lines between AdulterateFood and Dangerous food:

```
sed -n '/AdulterateFood/,/DangerousFood/p' file
```